# jquery .each , if statements do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove empty columns in sharepoint display forms. I am quite new to JQuery so bear with me!

I have:

```
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function (index) {
  if (index=6)
  {
    console.log("Mobile");
```

So it loops through all the formbody tags and when it comes to the sixth one it should display "Mobile" to `console.log` but it is just logging 'Mobile' x the count of the formbody tags. So it seems that the IF is not working. Can anyone advise ?

Comment: `if (index == 6)` ??

Comment: You are setting index value to 6 with `if (index =6)`. It  should be `if (index == 6)`.

Comment: You're *assigning* `index` to `6` on the first run of `.each`. You want to compare using `==`.

Answer (score 1):

With `index = 6` you are setting the value of the variable index. You should change it to `index == 6` or `index === 6` (in case you'd like to respect the type of the compared values).

```
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function (index) {
    if (index === 6) {
        console.log("Mobile");
    }
}
```

By the way, it seems that you'd like to apply something to the sixth column. You could use a direct selector for that, no need to search for it with a loop.

[:nth-child() selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
if (index =6)
{
console.log("Mobile");
}
```

To :

```
if (index == 6)
{
console.log("Mobile");
}
```

If you use a simple '=' you set the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function (index) {
  if (index == 6) {
  console.log("Mobile");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are new to passing functions as parameters as well.

Consider the following code:

```
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function(){});
```

In this example I am parsing through all occurrences of the `td.ms-formbody` selector. I am passing a function through to each occurrence which can then operate on each instance of that selector. Currently I'm doing nothing.

Now consider the following:

```
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function(){
    $("td.ms-formbody").index($(this));
});
```

This is one way of obtaining the index of each element. What JQuery is doing is getting all elements matching the selector and assigning them an arbitrary number based on the order in which they appear in the DOM. I can now operate on this information.

Using the correct conditional operator(`==`) and closing my if statement correctly, this will now log to the console if and when the `each()` function comes across a 6th element matching the selector.

```
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function(){
    if($("td.ms-formbody").index($(this)) == 6){
        console.log('Mobile');
    }
});
```

Comment: The parameter is assigned properly. :) Here's the documentation for .each(): https://api.jquery.com/each/